# Re-install linux by ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, installation, debian, grub

I have remote machine with OpenSUSE, and I cant interact with it only by SSH. I want to install Debian to this machine, how can I do it? I search answers, but each of them assumes, I have physical access to machine to launch setup, and this is something I'm not able to do. 
I already have USB flash drive inserted into remote machine. Can I, for example, install live system and chroot to it, or reconfigure bootloader to boot from flash, then re-install existing system?

Answer (score 0):

Would something like [this tutorial](http://www.underhanded.org/papers/debian-conversion/remotedeb.html#debootstrap) help?

AFAIK it is technically possible but fairly risky - the process has been likened to ["changing the tyres while driving"](https://serverfault.com/questions/208128/how-to-remotely-install-linux-via-ssh).

Good luck!

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.